# Reduce top & bottom padding in BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, padding, navigationbar

I would like to reduce top and bottom padding of BottomNavigationBar but I want to keep the same icon height and the bar height to 50 pixels :

```
  bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
    height: 50,
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
      showSelectedLabels: false,
      showUnselectedLabels: false,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      elevation: 5.0,
      currentIndex: 0,
      items: buildBottomBarItems(),
    ),
  )
```

the method to build bottom bar items :

```
    List<BottomNavigationBarItem> buildBottomBarItems() {
        List<BottomNavigationBarItem> _bottomBarItems = List();
        List<String> _iconNames = ["home", "search", "plus", "heart"];

        for (var i = 0; i < _iconNames.length; ++i) {

          _bottomBarItems.add(
           BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Container(
                  child: new Image.asset('assets/' + _iconNames[i] + '.png', width: 24, height: 24)
              ),
              title: Text('')
           )
         );
        }
     }
```

(in the present case there is an overflow of 4.0 pixels). Thank you

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the default space in BottomNavigationBar set the selectedFontSize to 0.
It will remove the default space available for the text.
BottomNavigationBar(
selectedFontSize: 0.0,
)